# MFC Application Crashes while closing

Tags: mfc, assert, crash

I had a working MFC application (a dialog application), I deleted some of its button and added a new button, but now when it closes the application crashes. It fails in one of **ASSERT()** macro. The debug assertions fails on these lines

File: afxtempl.h
Line: 558

When I view that code it was something like this

```
template<class TYPE, class ARG_TYPE>
void CArray<TYPE, ARG_TYPE>::AssertValid() const
{
    CObject::AssertValid();

    if (m_pData == NULL)
    {
        ASSERT(m_nSize == 0);
        ASSERT(m_nMaxSize == 0);
    }
    else
    {
        // here it fails
        ASSERT(m_nSize >= 0);
        ASSERT(m_nMaxSize >= 0);
        ASSERT(m_nSize <= m_nMaxSize);
        ASSERT(AfxIsValidAddress(m_pData, m_nMaxSize * sizeof(TYPE)));
    }
}
#endif //_DEBUG
```

Any clues as to what is going wrong? The application was working fine when earlier, but I messed it up.

Comment: what is the value of m_nSize?

Comment: it is not always enough to delete the control from the resources. Maybe there is code that still attempts to use it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd want to see what is in the stack trace leading up to the assertion - also what is in the various member variables. For example, if the cause is a double deletion, in a debug build you would expect to see the value 0xdddddddd in the value since the debug allocator sets freed memory to this value.

Answer (score 0):

I've see crazy things like this when I've inadvertently got duplicate resource ids defined in `resource.h`.  If the only thing you've changed is add/remove a few buttons, I would check this first then try a full rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

Few months ago I have the same kind of problem - MFC crash on closing. Later found that in a destructor I was trying to delete or free some memory which is already deleted but somehow passing the null checking before it.May be you can check this point.